# RestKit, Core Data, and Relationship problems. Parent object not recognizing child set

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, relationship

I am trying to map a relationship between Articles and the Photos that belong to them using RestKit. Both objects get stored properly when requesting the resource, but it seems the relationship does not persist. In fact, the Article model seems to not even respond to the Photos selector (This may be the 'duh' spot, but I will provide full code to be through).

I've provided all code in a gist, as I find it easier to look through and format then on StackOverflow. Sorry if this is actually an inconvenience.

https://gist.github.com/3733334

And here is the image of the core data model and the relationships set up (sorry, I had to combine them since I can only post 2 hyperlinks currently):

http://imageshack.us/a/img33/5039/stackoverflowissue.jpg

Everything seems to be working properlly except the relationship between the objects when I try to access photos via anArticle.photos. The selector is unrecognized. I set up a convience method in the Photo model to return all photos with a matching article ID, but I feel this is an un-ideal solution as it sort of removes the whole idea of creating a relationship.

I feel there may be something simple I am missing and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar issue only I'm using mogenerator for my core data models, so an NSSet is there.

Comment: UPDATE: Mine was a dumb mistake too, as I had failed to check to-many relationship in the CoreData modeler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So of course it was a "Duh" error. After some help from a local developer, he pointed out that my Photos variable in my Article.h file was an NSArray, and needed to be changed to an NSSet to store objects mapped by RestKit.

Answer (score 0):

Theres some inconsistency between different versions of RestKit. If you are using the latest one mappings should be set up as shown here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping. If you want to use entity classes for model specific methods make categories on your NSManagedObjects so that when you change your data model you can regenerate them (Do this only after you extract your methods to a category! Select an entity in your .xcdatamodeld and go to Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...).

I moved my mappings to the controller that is responsible for syncing with the remote API.

This shuld be helpful too: http://andriyadi.me/logging-in-restkit/.

Also Core Data guidelines stress that you should set up inverse relations (but it's not obligatory).

Fetching entities can also be done better in my opinion. In my project I have an NSObject subclass singleton that (among some other Core Data convenience functionalities) fetches by entity and predicate:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchEntities:(NSString *)entity usingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error) {
        RLog(@"Error fetching entity %@ using predicate %@", entity, predicate);
        abort();
    }
    if ([results count] >= 1) {
        return results;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

You can alter it to pass predicates as NSStrings too.

Side note:
Currently I'm also struggling with RestKit and object mapping myself :).

Comment: Hey Zamber, Thanks for the response. Since this post I've  set up the inverse relationship properties in the .xcdatanodeld. I believe I am using the master branch of RestKit, and I have followed that same object mapping guide. Would moving the mapping out of the classes have any impact on the relationship? I'll check into setting up the categories instead, see if that helps. Also, that Entity Fetcher looks very convient, I'll definitely try that one out.